# Xcode8にてAVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import AssetsLibrary

var documentsPath = NSTemporaryDirectory()
var fileName: String? = ""

class VideoDelegate : NSObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
        print("capture output : finish recording to \(outputFileURL)")
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {
        print("capture output: started recording to \(fileURL)")

    }
}
```

Xcode7までこのようなコードを書いてきましたが、
Type 'VideoDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate'
このようエラーを出されたことはありませんでした。
Xcode8 Swift3では使用出来ないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Swift3の命名規則変更により外部引数名と型が変わっているためです。

```
class VideoDelegate : NSObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
        print("capture output : finish recording to \(outputFileURL)")
    }

    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {
        print("capture output: started recording to \(outputFileURL)")
    }
}
```

第一引数のラベルは省略されるルールがなくなり、代わりに引数ラベルを取らないことを明記するため、`_`を追加する必要があります。

`didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:`が`didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt:`に変わり、`NSURL`が`URL`に変わりました。

`AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`の定義を再度確認するのが早いと思います。

---

詳細についてはこちらをどうぞ。

- [Better Translation of Objective-C APIs Into Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md)
- [Mutability and Foundation Value Types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md)
- [Establish consistent label behavior across all parameters including first labels](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md)

Comment: ありがとうございました。助かりました！